# <assemblyBinding> ignored in parent web.config

Tags: asp.net, configuration, assemblies, gac

I have a folder containing several websites, all using the same assemblies in the GAC. Each website also contains some 'custom' assemblies of their own that refer to the common assemblies.

There is a web.config in this folder, defining common settings for the sites, including the assemblies to load in a `<system.web>/<compilation>/<assemblies>` element.

What I want to be able to do is add a `<runtime>/<assemblyBinding>` section to redirect requests from the older 'custom' assemblies to the newer ones installed in the GAC. (Unfortunately, using machine.config or the GAC redirection policy aren't options as this will affect other sites.)

It seems that the `<assemblyBinding>` section is ignored unless it is in the website's own web.config, or the machine.config.

I've already come across the `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">` problem so I know it's not that.

Does anyone know if this is what is supposed to happen or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to happen. You did nothing wrong.

for more information, please take a look at 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28vs.71%29.aspx)